Matrix norm and range of singular values
In relation to another question about canonical angles I found the following in Ch. 6.4.3 in Golub and Van Loan, 4th ed,

I don't see why the 2-norm of the matrix $\big\|Q_{A}^{T}Q_{B}\big\|_{2}$ (i.e., the largest singular value $\sigma(Q_{A}^{T}Q_{B})$) is in the range $[0,1]$. The lower limit = $0$ I understand, since all singular values are non-negative real numbers. But what about the upper limit? Can you help me? Thank you!

2-norm is submultiplicative

I know that $\big|Q_{A}^{T}Q_{B}\big|{2}\leq \big|Q{A}^{T}\big|{2}\big|Q{B}\big|{2}$ but since the matrices $Q{A}$ and $Q_{B}$ are only semi-unitary and not unitary I stuggle to see why $\big|Q_{A}^{T}\big|{2}=1$ and  $\big|Q{B}^{T}\big|_{2}=1$

@Dennis We have
$$
|Q_A|_2^2 = |Q_A^T|_2^2 = |Q_A^TQ_A|_2 = |I|_2 = 1,
$$
noting that $|M|_2^2 = |M^T|_2^2 = |M|_2$ is generally true.

Although I do not know why but the statement (1) $|Q_A|2^2 = |Q_A^T|2^2$ seems intuitive for me. However, $|Q_A|2^2 = |Q_A^TQ_A|2$ is not clear for me. How to get the last step in  $|Q_A|{2}^2 = |Q_A|{2}|Q_A|{2} \overset{(1)}{=} |Q_A^{T}|{2}|Q_A|_2\overset{?}{=}|Q_A^TQ_A|_2$?

I got it why the matrix norm does not change under matrix transposition
Since the 2-norm of a matrix corresponds to the largest singular of that matrix and singular values do not change when transposing matrices $\big|Q_{A}\big|{2} =\big|Q{A}^{T}\big|_{2}$
Still, can you help me understand why $|Q_A^{T}|_{2}|Q_A|_2\overset{?}{=}|Q_A^TQ_A|_2$

@Dennis Marx $|Q_A|_2^2 = |Q^{\top}_AQ_A|_2$ can be proved by SVD of $Q_A$

@goldboy: thank you! that helped
